# how to create keydown event in c# Error 'System Windows Forms KeyEventArgs'

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

how to create keydown event in c# Error 'System Windows Forms KeyEventArgs'

Error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument ? how to create keydown event
>   EXP>>>[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
public event KeyEventHandler TextBoxKeyDow;

protected void OnTextBoxKeyDow()
{
    if (TextBoxKeyDow != null)
    {
        TextBoxKeyDow(this,new KeyEventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn to google -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No I Have create Event

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cOBd4.png

Comment: `TextBoxKeyDow(this, new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Down));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public event EventHandler BBBClick;
    protected void OnBBBClick()
    {
        if (BBBClick != null)
        {
            BBBClick(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }   
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnBBBClick();
    }
```

create keydown event  in user control
EXP>>>[image: Required image is displayed]